# Is there a way to configure a text terminal to display the SOH (^A) control character?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, putty

I need to look at some logs ([FIX protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Information_eXchange) messages from QuickFIX), which use the SOH character as a separator between fields.

I'm connecting to a CentOS server using PuTTY over SSH.

While I can log the session and then search-and-replace the SOH character with '||' (or something similar), I was wondering if there was a way to do it "live", via terminal settings.

Comment: I have the same problem with QuickFIX! I'd also like to view the SOH character in the Linux terminal. Please let me know if you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly what you mean by

> to do it via terminal settings.

For instance, you can easily visualize SOH by substituting it  with this sequence of operations,

```
   cat -v file | sed 's/\^A/\t/g' | less
```

From [the manual entry for cat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat):

> **-v, --show-nonprinting**
>   use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB

Now Start Of Heading (SOH) has been transformed into <kbd>^</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, and the Stream Editor `sed` replaces it with a Tab (change this as you see fit.

Or, when editing the file with `vim`, you can display non-printable characters by hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> to enter command mode, then hit

```
 :set list
```

and then

```
 :set nolist
```

to return to the previous situation.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer! I did come across solutions based on cat and sed elsewhere. I wonder if it's possible to make the terminal do the substitutions or just display the control character as ^A. The reason is that I'm viewing these logs online while the process is running. They're not in a file.

Comment: @Plumenator No, there is not a console-setting, if this what you mean. There may be an application setting, like I said.